# How to get the alt tag from an image field in twig?

Tags: 8, theming

I have a page of field images which are coming out quite weirdly when I kint their values. I can't seem to get the image url and the alt tag.

The code in the twig file looks like this:

`field--field-staff-gallery.html.twig`

```
{% for item in items %}
    {{ kint(item) }}
{% endfor %}
```

It's output looks like this:
[image]

Now I can easily get to the url by doing:

```
{% for item in items %}
    {{ file_url(item.content['#markup']) }}
{% endfor %}
```

So how can I get the alt tag?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get the alt of image with:

```
item.content['#item'].value.alt
```

Comment: as you can see from the output above I don't seem to have the `#item` output on this field

Comment: In the field twig there is two foreach one for multiple and other for no multiple fields, and also check your field display settings from *admin/structure/types/manage/YourContentType/display* i have Image as formatter not url to image, what you have ?

Comment: ah, ok so that worked. i changed it to image. it was on url to image. not to be a bother, but how do I then get the url from this? `item.content['#url']` is `NULL`

Comment: The single field #item is only added by the image field formatter, but the field items `element['#items']` are added for all field formatters. For a single value field it doesn't matter and you can use both, for a multi value field you need to add a key to the loop to access each item.